# App breaks always on display in android oreo (Samsung Note 8)

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-7.0-nougat, android-8.0-oreo

I have an android app that:

- runs as a foreground service
- uses screencast/screencapture

When using Android 7.0, always on display worked great.  Now that my phone is updated to 8.0, always on display simply doesn't work--the screen just turns off.

The target SDK is 26.  My device is a tmobile samsung note 8 device.

Comment: Can you add a picture comparing both?

Comment: Hmmm one is a black screen (turned off--not just black)... the other is the always on display screen.  Is it necessary?

Comment: Check out 8.0 Behaviour changes *Background execution* - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html

Comment: My app makes the appropriate calls for starting the foreground service.  Again, my app continues to function perfectly...  its just the always on display doesn't appear.

Comment: It looks like that feature is disabled in oreo - https://www.androidauthority.com/enable-always-display-android-oreo-rom-800358/

Comment: On samsung devices, always on display has been available for quite some time.  This question is probably specific to samsung devices, so far as I can tell.